# Setting DatagridVIew column format to numeric is not aligning the column to the right

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, format

I have a DataGridView bound to the DataTable.
I am setting the default cell style to numeric but it doesn't align the column to the right. 
Is it the expected behavior?

```
private void shipmentDetailsDataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            shipmentDetailsDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
            shipmentDetailsDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
            shipmentDetailsDataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
            shipmentDetailsDataGridView.Columns[Glossary.Total].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
            shipmentDetailsDataGridView.Columns[Glossary.TotalInvoice].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
            shipmentDetailsDataGridView.Columns[Glossary.UnitPrice].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
            shipmentDetailsDataGridView.Columns[Glossary.Quantity].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N0";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the expected behavior.  From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx) - emphasis mine:

> The Format property specifies how cell values are formatted *as strings*.

To right-align the column, try the following:

```
shipmentDetailsDataGridView.Columns[Glossary.Quantity].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```